# how to pass checkboxes with request.get

Tags: checkbox

I am trying to download several tables from [this website](http://www.bom.gov.au/water/designRainfalls/revised-ifd/?year=2016).

It has 2 checkboxes that I must pass, and I am not sure how to.

I have tried using the same cookies as my browser but it didn't work (with [browsercookie](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/browsercookie)).

Here is how my code is:

```
url = 'http://www.bom.gov.au/water/designRainfalls/revised-ifd/?coordinate_type=dd&latitude=-35&longitude=144&sdmin=true&sdhr=true&sdday=true&user_label=&year=2016'    
requests.get(url, cookies=browsercookie)
```

Using the command gives a `<Response [200]>`, but the website thinks that I have not ticked the checkbox and will return me to a website requesting me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work!

The browsercookie command that I used was not working properly (not sure why). So I created the cookies by myself and it is working. Did it by accessing the website itself, checked the cookies that it was using, and then created the cookies with:

```
browsercookie = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
broswercookie.set('Name','Content','Domain','Path')
```